# MAT, YTD, MAT-LY, YTD-LY formula in Tableu

Tags: tableau-api

I'm newbie in Tableu. I have Table like this above, i want to get YTD201502 and MAT201502.

Please advice

Period,  Region, Sales
201401   AAAA   , 100
201402   AAAA   , 100
201403   AAAA   , 100
201404   AAAA   , 100
201405   AAAA   , 90
201406   AAAA   , 98
201407   AAAA   , 120
201408   AAAA   , 110
201409   AAAA   , 80
201410   AAAA   , 67
201411   AAAA   , 75
201412   AAAA   , 112
201501   AAAA   , 113
201502   AAAA   , 110

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing:

YTD201502 is the total sales
MAT201502 is the running total

Once you've connected to your data source your sales will automatically be a measure. Just double click on it and it will total the sales. It may appear as a bar, just select the "Show Me" tab on the top right and select the table layout out. Presto your total sales.

To get your running sales I'm guessing its by year. On the above drag your Period pill into the columns shelf. It should auto set to year. You will have the total sales per year in a total. In the measures values select the sales pill drop down menu and go to Quick Table Calculation -> Running Total.

If you want the sum total displayed of the column go to Analysis-> Totals -> Show Column Grand Totals